# Fix Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, multithreading

EDIT:
I did like this with the help of my stack overflow friends  inside my thread to display the video view inside of the dialog in the android but it freezes my application help me Big thanks in advance

This is My activity from the Thread :

```
Auto_Bucket_Tests_Thread = new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void run() {

                while(Test_Completed==false)
                {
                    if(Login.Bucket_Status==true && Video_Status==false)
                    {

                        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Bucket_Open_Error();

                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else if(Login.Bucket_Status==false && Video_Status==true)
                    {
                    videodialog.cancel();   
                    }
                }
                Auto_Bucket_Tests_Thread.stop();
            }
        });

     }



        protected void Bucket_Open_Error() {
        videodialog = new Dialog(this);
        videodialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        videodialog.setContentView(R.layout.videodialog);
        videodialog.show();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams layout_params =new WindowManager.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layout_params.copyFrom(videodialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
        layout_params.dimAmount=0;
        videodialog.getWindow().setAttributes(layout_params);

        final VideoView video = (VideoView)videodialog.findViewById(R.id.videoView_dialog);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.doorsclosing);
        video.setVideoURI(uri);
        video.start();
        video.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Video_Status=true;
                video.start();
                //app_message.show();


            }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to create a Handler from a back thread. If u dont want the handler to communicate with the UI thread then create a different thread and not Handler. If u want the Handler to communicate with the UI thread then u need pass a Looper to the constructor.

> new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

EDIT: replace

> runOnUiThread

with

> new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post

runOnUiThread is an Activity method which create a handler and post the Runnable in the UI thread, but because youare running on a back thread (created new Thread and ran it) you cant post to the UI like this becuase the new Handler has no connection to the UI (hence the didint call Looper prepare exeception).

Comment: Sorry for late replay dude i didn't get you can you please tell me again how to do this because i am new to this @EE66

Comment: Dude i did like what you said but it freezes application please help me i posted my code above @EE66

Comment: Change the while to If. U have opened multiple videos. This is why u stuck your UI thread

Comment: My bad. Don't remove the while just change the value of test complete

Comment: K dude i solved it  with your answer and i didn't change value of while Thanks for help dude @EE66